# Worklight, Adapter-Based Authentication for Android, app does not exist on the server

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

Im new to Worklight, Im trying to run the AdapterBasedAuthenticationProject from the tutorial of IBM worklight. [Sample here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/AdapterBasedAuthenticationProject.zip)

After deployed the auth-adapter and build the app, this app run ok on the Worklight console. However, when I make the android version and run on virtual machine, I can not get the secret data. 
When I click on "Get secret data" button on android, error occurs

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0332E: The application AdapterBasedAuthApp for the environment android does not exist on the server. Cannot register this client. [project AdapterBasedAuthenticationProject]
```

[Image here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yw3uk0zo20exdoy/Android_error.jpg?dl=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looks like you are using JRE 1.8 (Java 8). Note that Worklight does not support Java 8 - downgrade to either Java 6 or 7.
2. Make sure you have:

   - Added the Android environment
   - Deployed the Android environment (right-click on the your-app\android folder and select Run As > Build and Deploy)

Those are crucial steps in order for the server to recognize a request originating from Android

Also, I don't understand what do you mean by "virtual machine", as it is not obvious from the screen shot. It just looks like a resized browser window.

Comment: virtual machine means an android device created by sdk. After downgraded to java 7, it works. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue today. In my case Java version was not the issue the issue was incorrect wlAppVersion number in wlclient.properties, 
make sure it is same as in application-descriptor.xml.